# How can I fling to next or previous card only?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, cardview

I am working on a very basic application showing some cards with an image and text. It's working perfectly in the sense that it is centered well and it snaps well. However when I scroll/fling fast, the card which lands can be third or even the fourth from the current card.

I want to restrict it so that, when the user flings right(however fast), it should land at just one previous card, and if he/she flings left, it should go to the next immediate card. Is it possible to do so ?

Comment: I think you need some kind of vertical `ViewPager`

Comment: just like scroll events, there are fling events as well. Use that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, I think you should solve it by changing the speed of fling,
RecyclerView has fling method, you just override it.

```
float FLING_SPEED = 0.5f;

@Override
public boolean fling(int velocityX, int velocityY)
{
    // FLING_SPEED between (0, 1) => slow down, greater 1 => speed up
    // velocityY for vertical, velocityX for horizontal
    velocityY *= FLING_SPEED; 
    return super.fling(velocityX, velocityY);
}
```